# Tracing what went wrong with MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a local in-house client application that relies on steel server MySQL 5.6 database in our closet.  This morning, people suddenly couldn't log in.  The client server said it couldn't connect with the database.  On the database server itself, the MySQL service was running.  I stopped and started it again and things went back to normal.  However, I don't know what went wrong and I'd like to know why this happened to see if it's something I can prevent in the future.  What are some diagnostics I can do to see what happened with the server this morning?

Comment: Not directly answering your question but "database in our closet"? How much would it cost to replace the data and how much would it cost to host the database where it can be properly provisioned?

Comment: What monitoring/logging software do you have running at the moment? You have to run such software **continuously** (i.e. not just when things go wrong) because then you can compare situation good/situation bad! Is your server Windows/*nix? If *nix, I suggest that you use sysstat at least. What does the MySQL error log have to say? Does your syslog say anything? Is the database accessed through a webserver? Could you run the `mysql` client when nobody could connect with your app? Did you try anything else to diagnose at the time? We need more information.

Comment: Anything in the log files?

Comment: You could, at least, write if you are running on Windows or Linux... Too little info here to help but for sure the first thing should be the error log.